# Getting access_token for plaid for sandbox environment running

Tags: plaid

I am trying to get a sample `public_token` or `access_token` for [plaid](https://plaid.com/docs/api/) in sandbox mode. I need the `access_token` for api's like `auth` and `institutions`.
I ran the demo [here](https://plaid.com/demo/), by choosing a bank and entering the credentials as
`user_good` and `pass_good`. When I inspected the page I did get a `public_token` in response. But I am unable to exchange this for an `access_token`, with the `client_id` and `secret` I got from singing up in the [dashboard](https://dashboard.plaid.com/overview). I keep getting the error `INVALID_TOKEN`. How do I get the `access_token` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The public_token you get by inspecting the page of the demo app, is for the client_id and secret of that demo app. It wont work with your client_id and secret.

You need to run the demo app locally, with your client_id and secret. Look at this - https://github.com/plaid/quickstart/tree/master/node

Follow the readme file to run the demo locally, but with your client_id and secret and then inspect the page like you did above. The public_token you get this time will work with your client_id and secret :)